Association abort does not close TCP connection
Using pydicom store SCP. The after sending the files, PACS does not release the association. Hence the association is aborted due to timeout
E: Network timeout reached
I: Aborting Association

And then I ran ss -ant command , and I see the TCP connection is in ESTAB state. For every association, a new TCP connection is created and it is not closed even though on_assoc_aborted() is triggered
How do I make sure the connection is closed after the association is aborted as I have 70+ connections in ESTAB state even though no associations are open and its been a few hours they are in ESTAB state

Can you create an issue on the pynetdicom github repo?

I created an issue. Please let me know if any more details needed
